# Python - change header color of dataframe and save it to excel file

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` where i want to change the header background color, apply borders and save it excel file in .xlsx extension.

I have tried styleframe, some functionalities in openpyxl and tried to write udf s, But nothing seemed to work.

Comment: Why don't you include in the question what you tried. It's okay if its broken.

Comment: Do you use Windows? If so, you can have Python interface with COM for full access to Excel object library.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution using [StyleFrame](https://github.com/DeepSpace2/StyleFrame) package that you mentioned.

```
import pandas as pd
from styleframe import StyleFrame, Styler, utils

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [1, 2, 3]})
sf = StyleFrame(df)

sf.apply_headers_style(styler_obj=Styler(bold=True,
                                         bg_color=utils.colors.green,
                                         border_type=utils.borders.medium))

sf.to_excel('output.xlsx').save()
```

I would recommend you to make sure that you have the lastest version of StyleFrame installed.

```
pip install -U styleframe
```

Comment: Actually, it depends on pandas lower to 1.2.0, which is out of date

Comment: I do not know if it's a different version. but for latest versions the import doesn't work.
should be changed to "from styleframe import StyleFrame, Styler, utils"